# How to avoid printing empty array elements?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I know how to do this for numeric datatypes but please tell my for string arrays.

Say I have a string array of 10 elements in java. Some elements contain words but others contain NOTHING.

How do I run a for loop which prints only the non empty elements?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried if(!(x[i].equals(""))) and if(!(x[i].equals(null))) but ran into java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: How did you do it for "numeric datatypes", and why doesn't that work here?

Comment: @scottHunter for numeric datatypes I do if((x[i]!=null){print..} and it works

Comment: `x[i].equals(null)` is never going to be `true`

Comment: @fantaghirocco then what should I try, I can't think of any other way

Comment: when x[i] is null , .equals throws NPE - `!StringUtils.isEmpty(x[i])` from apache.commons.lang should solve your problem

Comment: @fantaghirocco thank you finally some useful response and not 5 downvotes

Comment: "...and why didn't that work here?"

Comment: If you don't want to use commons lang then `if(null == x[i] || x[i].trim().equals(""))` try this.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: Isn't that the *opposite* of what was asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print empty elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == null || arr[i].trim().isEmpty()) {
       System.out.println("Element " + i " + " is null or empty.");
    }
}
```

The print non-empty elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ( arr[i] != null && !arr[i].trim().isEmpty())) {
       System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```